# press enter key and user control event happen

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a `userControl(DT_Navigator)`. there is a button (`btnNew`) in it.
I wrote the click button event for it:

```
public void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        btnNew.Enabled = false;
}
```

I use the user control button in another project and wrote another click event for it:

```
public void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        btnNew.Enabled = false;
}
```

but, when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, just the first event that I defined in user control, executes. However I want both events to execute.

when I click on `btnNew`, both events trigger, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, only one event triggers.

how can I fix the problem? Thanks...

Comment: what ui framework? winforms, wpf, etc?

Comment: @DanielA.White winforms

Comment: Try attaching the second event handler to the `Click` event rather than the `MouseClick` (they are not the same event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`DT_Navigator.btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(DTnewItem);`